# pgfplots ybar intervals on the left instead of on the right

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to make a `pgfplots` `ybar interval` plot with the interval extending to the *left* of the marked point.

Here is a minimal non-working example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=0,xmax=5,
            ymin=0,ymax=1
        ]
            \addplot+[ybar interval,fill=blue!50] coordinates {(1,1) (2,0.25) (3,0.11111) (4,0.0625) (5,0.04)};            
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample code output]

As you can see, the intervals extend to the right.  I would rather it look like this:

[image: desired output]

without having to do this (how I produced the above):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}    
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=0,xmax=5,
            ymin=0,ymax=1
        ]
            \addplot+[ybar interval,forget plot,fill=blue!50,mark=none] coordinates {(0,1) (1,0.25) (2,0.11111) (3,0.0625) (4,0.04) (5,0)};            
            \addplot+[only marks] coordinates {(1,1) (2,0.25) (3,0.11111) (4,0.0625) (5,0.04)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there a key that I can set, or another, cleaner way to get what I want?

Comment: But your second plot is not what the data says. Is it intentional?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.  I do want the diagram to look like the second graphic.

Answer (score 4):

Since all your bars have the same width, there's no reason to use `ybar interval`. Instead, you can use `ybar, bar width=1, bar shift=-0.5` (this requires `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}` or greater).

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=0,xmax=5,
            ymin=0,ymax=1,
            bar width=1,
            bar shift=-0.5
        ]
            \addplot+[ybar,fill=blue!50] coordinates {(1,1) (2,0.25) (3,0.11111) (4,0.0625) (5,0.04)};            
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```